# How to inspect webpacked ES6 modules in chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, webpack, es6-modules

Prior to using Webpack to bundle my application, I was creating modules using IIFE's and then attaching them onto the `window` object so that I could access them. This made debugging in the chrome browser pretty simple since the modules are all globally available and I could inspect them with breakpoints.

I've recently transitioned to using Webpack to bundle my application, which has been great. However, now when I set breakpoints and want to inspect the imported modules, I'm unable to do so by referencing the module name. I'm pretty sure this is because under the hood, Webpack renames the modules to something else.

Here's an example of the import statements in a particular file (btw, each of the imported modules is importing an object):

[image: import statements]

And in that same file, when I set a breakpoint, I'd like to be able to inspect the contents of the modules like I used to be able to. In the image below, I'm trying to access the `CustomHelpers` module which is just a collection of helper functions stored in an object.

[image: chrome console with breakpoint]

**Any thoughts on how I can reference these imported modules while debugging in the Chrome console?**

To clarify, my `webpack.config.js` is working and I have sourcemaps enabled which is why I'm seeing the original file instead of the garbled bundle.js files. Specifically, I'm just trying to inspect the **modules** I imported and see their contents.

Comment: Are you using minified bundles? I know Chrome breakpoints on sourcemaps don't work brilliantly if the generated scripts are minified. Even when they're not it's hit and miss though. You're usually better off just putting 'debugger' statements in your source, as they have the exact same effect!

Answer (score 3):

There is an open issue on Webpack's Github. The best answer for me is the second point [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3957#issuecomment-567987472).

> Memorise the webpack naming conventions. If you are at a breakpoint, and your import is similar to import UserModel from 'xxx'. Then the webpack bindings are usually called **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__UserModel**. The devtools are usually friendly enough to autocomplete for you if you start typing __ and then go from there.

Answer (score 2):

in webpack.config.js:

- set debug flag to true
- indicate a devtool

like this:

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./index.js", //"./tryfirst/tree.js", //
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
},
debug: true,
devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
module: {
    loaders: [
    ...
```

If you are used to starting babel from commandline, you can set the same options on the commandline like this:

```
babel src -d lib --presets es2015 --sourceMaps inline; webpack --devtool eval-source-map
```

The same line can be added to package.json as a script. Just add something like this to the "scripts" section:

```
"scripts": {
  ...,
  "test": "babel src -d lib --presets es2015 --sourceMaps inline; webpack --devtool eval-source-map"
 },
```

Then you can start it easily from commandline without having to keep in mind all the options and flags:

```
npm run test
```

Code within the scripts works exactly (for the most part at least) like what you type on your console. npm run test (or whatever you call the script) is the shortcut you can use from then on.

If it still doesn't stop at breakpoints try adding the command "debugger;" at the desired breakpoint *inside your actual javascript code*. Looks funny but usually does the trick. Chrome will find them and set breakpoints there for you.

Comment: Hm so I think you're misunderstanding my question - I've got my webpack.config.js working and I have sourcemaps enabled, which is why its mapping back to the original file instead of the garbled bundle.js file. However, when I set breakpoints in the sourcemap and I want to specifically inspect the contents of the imported MODULES, that's where I can't see them.

Comment: Hi @wmock, I think I understood your question, but it works for me with this configuration - even with breakpoints set in a node_module. Just tried to find out if 'code'exclude: /node_modules/'code' in the babel-loader configuration makes a difference, but in my case it is set and it works anyway. On the other hand occurring errors (and that is usually when you need debugging) sometimes makes otherwise working sourcemaps go up in smoke all of a sudden, but that is not restricted to module files.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up - I wonder if its because I'm missing the `debug: true` configuration in my `webpack.config.js` file because everything else in your configuration is what I have in mine as well.

Comment: unfortunately adding `debug: true` doesn't seem to solve the issue. It seems like the default object I'm importing in can't be inspected in the chrome console :(

Comment: @wmock have you figured this out by chance? I'm running into the same problem

Comment: @vernak2539 unfortunately i haven't

Comment: Same issue for me too. If you ever come up with a working solution let us know. Until then `console.log`...

Answer (score 0):

You can try my webpack plugin, which will add debug variables for every import

https://github.com/trias/debug-import-vars-webpack-plugin

install it

```
npm i -D debug-import-vars-webpack-plugin
```

and add it to your webpack.config.js

```
const DebugImportVarsPlugin = require("debug-import-vars-webpack-plugin");

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [new DebugImportVarsPlugin()],
};
```

Now you can set a breakpoint in your code and the imported variables like `CustomHelpers` should be visible in the debugger.